# Executar outra ação durante um await Task.Delay

Tags: c#, visual-studio, task, async-await, timer

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde chega uma determinada parte do código em que preciso colocar um:

```
 await Task.Delay(tempo);
```

Porem, ao mesmo tempo em que tenho que **esperar** esse tempo eu preciso **executar** uma ação de 10 em 10 minutos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já quebrei a cabeça pensando em como posso fazer isso e nada veio em mente.

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isto e como.

Comment: Chama outro thread com alguma atividade para ser executada em paralelo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom dia,
Pelo que você informou você necessita de uma nova thread para realizar a ação de 10 minutos. Neste caso você tem duas possibilidades simples de utilizar:

- **Task**: você cria uma nova `Task` da biblioteca `System.Threading.Tasks` com um `while` e um `await Task.Delay(tempo);` assim a task será executada constantemente, no caso da task ele executa a ação e depois de completamente executada a ação vai chegar no delay e esperar o tempo determinado;

  Task _task_execucao_leitura;

  ```
  void main(){
      _task_execucao_leitura = tf.StartNew(this.metodo_desejado);
  }

  async void metodo_desejado(){
      while (true)
      {
          await Task.Delay(_tempo_ler_dados);
          ação desejada
      }
  }
  ```
- **Timer**: uma outra opção utilizar um `Timer` da biblioteca do `System.Threading` esta ação executa uma ação em um intervalo determinado, no fim do intervalo a ação é executada novamente, tendo ela sido finalizada na primeira execução ou não;

  Timer timerLeitura;

  ```
  void main(){
   timerLeitura = new Timer(new TimerCallback(leituraMetodo), null, tempoInicio, tempoLeitura);

  }

  void leituraMetodo(object obj)
  {
      ação desejada
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta forma também:

```
void DoWorkPollingTask()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Faça alguma coisa...
            await Task.Delay(time_to_sleep);
        }
    });
}
```

Desta forma você irá rodar o método de forma assíncrona e em paralelo com outras atividades.